# Excel SUM dynamic range returned from database

Tags: excel, sum, formula

I am new to excel and I am trying to write an excel formula where I sum all the values from a single column. The data is returned from a .net application so I am using a template file and each column as a suffix which is **%%=sso.qty** for example. So its only when a report is run through the application that there is actual data in each column.

I want a formula which will dynamically add all values in a column regardless of cell range. So if my suffix is in cell K10 how would the formula know to adjust the range based on how many rows of data there is?

Does anyone know a good way of doing this?

Comment: Where will this formula be placed?  In a different column?

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables Ideally it will be the same column below the final value. So its summing each value and working out a total.

Comment: I would strongly suggest putting it in a different cell; otherwise, how do you know where the formula will go if the number of rows imported varies every time?

Comment: Is there no logic that can be written where if the range exceeds a certain length that it adjusts to a new length?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the formula will be placed in a different column, you can `SUM` an entire column by specifying the column without a row reference, like this:

```
=SUM(K:K)
```

Comment: I am getting a circular reference because the formula is in the same column as the sum cell range.

Comment: Correct; if you put the formula in the same column as the range you are summing, this will happen.